# Cant show alert while trying to make a simple react-native-app

Tags: react-native, expo, tic-tac-toe

Im trying to make a tic-tack-toe game as a simple react-native app. But I cant make the alert work while trying to get the game to alert that player 1 or two wins when getting "3 in row". Can somebody see what I did wrong or give me some advice.

Everything is working exept that the Alert and the this.initializeGame(); under the part where I want to get the winner.

If someone would know if there is a "better" practice to name the variables const or let im also wondering that. :)

Thank you!

Here is the code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Alert, } from 'react-native';
import { MaterialCommunityIcons as Icon } from 'react-native-vector-icons'

export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      gameState: [
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]
      ],
      currentPlayer: 1,
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.initializeGame();
  }

  initializeGame = () => {
    this.setState({gameState:
      [
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]
      ],
      currentPlayer: 1,
    });
  }

  getWinner = () => {
    const NUM_TILES = 3;
    var arr = this.state.gameState;
    var sum;
    var i = 0;

//rows
  for (i; 1 < NUM_TILES; i++) {
      sum = arr[i][0] + arr[i][1] + arr[i][2];
      if (sum == 3) { return 1; }
      else if (sum == -3) { return -1; }
    }
//colums
  for (i; 1 < NUM_TILES; i++) {
      sum = arr[0][i] + arr[1][i] + arr[2][i];
      if (sum == 3) { return 1; }
      else if (sum == -3) { return -1; }
    }
  //diagonals
  sum = arr[0][0] + arr[1][1] + arr[2][2];
  if (sum == 3) { return 1; }
  else if (sum == -3) { return -1; } 

  sum = arr[2][0] + arr[1][1] + arr[0][2];
  if (sum == 3) { return 1; }
  else if (sum == -3) { return -1; }

  //If no winners
  return 0;
  }

  onTilePress = (row, col) => {
     //makes sure that the tiles dont change
    var value = this.state.gameState[row][col];
    if (value !== 0) { return; }

    //sets currant player
    var currentPlayer = this.state.currentPlayer;

    //sets the correct tile
    var arr = this.state.gameState.slice();
    arr [row][col] = currentPlayer;
    this.setState({gameState: arr});

    //switches player
    var nextPlayer = (currentPlayer == 1) ? -1 : 1;
    this.setState({currentPlayer: nextPlayer});

    //check for winners
    var winner = this.getWinner();
    if (winner == 1) {
      Alert.alert("Player 1 is the winner");
      this.initializeGame();
    } else if (winner == -1) {
      Alert.alert("Player 2 is the winner");
      this.initializeGame();
    }
  }

  renderIcon = (row, col) => {
    var value = this.state.gameState[row][col];
    switch(value)
    {
      case 1: return <Icon name="close" style={styles.tileX} />;
      case -1: return <Icon name="circle-outline" style={styles.tileO} />;
      default: return <View />;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>     
      <View style={{flexDirection: "row"}}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.onTilePress(0, 0)} style={[styles.tile, { borderLeftWidth: 0, borderTopWidth: 0 }]}>
          {this.renderIcon(0, 0)}
        </TouchableOpacity>    
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.onTilePress(0, 1)} style={[styles.tile, { borderTopWidth: 0, }]}>
          {this.renderIcon(0, 1)}
        </TouchableOpacity>    
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.onTilePress(0, 2)} style={[styles.tile, { borderRightWidth: 0, borderTopWidth: 0 }]}>
          {this.renderIcon(0, 2)}
      </TouchableOpacity> 
      </View>

      <View style={{flexDirection: "row"}}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.onTilePress(1, 0)} style={[styles.tile, { borderLeftWidth: 0 }]}>
          {this.renderIcon(1, 0)}
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.onTilePress(1, 1)} style={[styles.tile, { }]}>
          {this.renderIcon(1, 1)}
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.onTilePress(1, 2)} style={[styles.tile, { borderRightWidth: 0 }]}>
          {this.renderIcon(1, 2)}
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>  

      <View style={{flexDirection: "row"}}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.onTilePress(2, 0)} style={[styles.tile, { borderBottomWidth: 0, borderLeftWidth: 0, }]}>
          {this.renderIcon(2, 0)}
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.onTilePress(2, 1)} style={[styles.tile, { borderBottomWidth: 0, }]}>
          {this.renderIcon(2, 1)}
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.onTilePress(2, 2)} style={[styles.tile, { borderBottomWidth: 0, borderRightWidth: 0,
        }]}>
          {this.renderIcon(2, 2)}
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>  

      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  tile: { 
    borderWidth: 10,
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
  },
  tileX: {
    color: "red",
    fontSize: 60,
  },
  tileO: {
    color: "green",
    fontSize: 60,
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to give some more information on the error that you're getting? I think it might be related to the calculation not returning the desired answer, or any answer.

Comment: thank you so much, I did edit it. I explained it bad. Its not an error its more that the Alert is not showing and the this.initializeGame(); function is not working. :)

Comment: Can you please mark your question as solved if the answer below has helped you?Alternatively, you can comment on the answer to get a better answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like everything you did is fine, except your algorithm for the `getWinner()` function. There were many things wrong with this function, for example, you had the for loop ending condition as `1 < NUM_OF_TILES` where `NUM_OF_TILES` is 3. And also you have to reinitialize the `i` to 0 when moving from rows to columns because `i` is already 2 at the end of first for loop.

I have updated this function for you as follows:

```
  getWinner = () => {
    const NUM_TILES = 3;
    var arr = this.state.gameState;
    var sum;
    var i = 0;

    //rows
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_TILES; i++) {
      sum = arr[i][0] + arr[i][1] + arr[i][2];
      if (sum == 3) {
        return 1;
      } else if (sum == -3) {
        return -1;
      }
    }

    //colums
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_TILES; i++) {
      sum = arr[0][i] + arr[1][i] + arr[2][i];
      if (sum == 3) {
        return 1;
      } else if (sum == -3) {
        return -1;
      }
    }
    //diagonals
    sum = arr[0][0] + arr[1][1] + arr[2][2];
    if (sum == 3) {
      return 1;
    } else if (sum == -3) {
      return -1;
    }

    sum = arr[2][0] + arr[1][1] + arr[0][2];
    if (sum == 3) {
      return 1;
    } else if (sum == -3) {
      return -1;
    }

    //If no winners
    return 0;
  };
```

You can find the working code at: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-native-4f2yu I have not tested all use-cases btw, but hopefully it puts you in the right direction.

Comment: thank you! In what way was the for loop ending condition as 1 < NUM_OF_TILES where NUM_OF_TILES is 3 wrong? I want to understand, but I didnt see any difference in the code? :) I did but the loop there to try to go trough the rows versus columns. :)

Comment: Well its wrong because logically 1 is *less than* 3 (aka NUM_OF_TILES). Your for loop was going in an endless loop. You can try and see what I mean by just doing console logs. The difference in the code is that I am using `i < NUM_TILES` where `i` is incremented after every loop, instead of being a static number. I would suggest you to read more on for loops here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

Comment: Also, just a reminder, please marked this question (by marking the answer as the solution) as solved if you are satisfied with the answer.